# SQL Choose a manager in whose department the total value of sales for 1990 is the highest

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a hard time trying to figure out the way the tables Sales_order and Employees are connected.

The question is "How can I extract data on the manager with the highest value of sales for 1990 within his department if there is no common column between these tables?"

[image: Diagram]

[image: Tables]

Comment: Don't post links to things like Google Drives with files for users to download; they won't. The majority of users who answer here are subject matter experts, and know far too well the dangers and foolishness of downloading a file from a complete stranger on a file sharing site. If the information is important, include it in the contents of the question as text. Data can be supplied as DDL and DML statements.

Comment: Can you try describing what you know about the dabatase schema?
Expecting someone to download the file and mess with it is quite a long shot.

Comment: Do managers have customers and thereby sales_orders?

Comment: Thank you for your replies! I also attached the schema screenshots, hope it describes the idea of the database.  Sorry, it's the first time of me posting a question, so I tried to include all the information I could

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Answering to Do managers have customers and thereby sales_orders? – 
I'm new to SQL and find this relational database a bit confusing, but I suppose managers are referred to as salesperson in Customer table

Comment: If you are confused, then ask the people who gave you this homework / quiz. There is no obvious way to know what persons are "managers". In addition, it is a bit concerning that your question seems to be quite complex for introductory SQL class. But the first step is to calculate total sales by department. Break the problem down into smaller pieces.

Comment: I see it now - employee has a FK to itself - so that is how you know who is a manager.

Answer (score 0):

join indirectly via customer to get manager_id

```
select top 1 manager_id,sum(total)
from   salesorders so
join   customers cus on cus.customer_id = so.customer_id
join   employee emp on emp.employee_id = cus.salesperson_id
where  so.order_date between '1999-01-01' and '1999-12-31'
group  by manager_id
order sum(total) desc
```